# Knockout Style binding Top and Left not working

Tags: css, knockout.js

I can't for the life in me understand why this isn't working. This should be a softball for someone. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/ZsA4f/2/

HTML

```
<div data-bind="foreach:Zones">
    <div class="container" data-bind="style:{ top: ZoneY, left: ZoneX }, text: ZoneTest"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.container { position: absolute; font-size: .75em; }
```

Javascript

```
var viewModel = {
    Zones: ko.observableArray([
        {
            ZoneX: 100,
            ZoneY: 100,
            ZoneTest: "hello world"
        },
        {
            ZoneX: 200,
            ZoneY: 200,
            ZoneTest: "rage!"
        }
])        
};

ko.applyBindings();
```

Comment: Sorry but what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to specify a unit. 100 and 200 should be `100px` and `200px` respectively

http://jsfiddle.net/ZsA4f/6/

Comment: Bwaaahahaha!  Got me too.  I was using a ko.observable(86) instead of ko.observable("86px"). Thanks daedalus28. A three year old answer still relevant.

Comment: I had the same problem but in the opposite direction - too much info -> ko.observable("86px;") - must not have the ";" there.