# Knockout two-way left and top binding

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

It's known [how to bind left and top by knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12013571/2631076).

But it allows to set a value in one direction only (model-to-view).

How can I keep two-way binding, so that when I change the position of an object (drag-and-drop) it will be actual in the model (view-to-model)?

If it isn't possible by knockout, how is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you will need to create a custom binding.  Create a binding that accepts to the position, then in the binding create an event handler to listen for when the positions changed and write the changes back to the properties originally passed

This blog post should help

http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/using-custom-options-with-knockoutjs-drag-and-drop/